# Is "attributeName" required for @Convert on a Map<String, String> attribute?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

We are migrating from Eclipselink to Hibernate (5.6.14) and, with Hibernate, a previously green unit test in some legacy code runs into the following exception:

```
[ERROR] someTestWasRun(com.abc.AbcTest)  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
       [... long stack ...]
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Convert placed on Map attribute [Abc.colors] must define attributeName of 'key' or 'value'
        at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionPropertyHolder.applyLocalConvert(CollectionPropertyHolder.java:133)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionPropertyHolder.buildAttributeConversionInfoMaps(CollectionPropertyHolder.java:88)
```

The attribute in question is a `Map<String, String>`:

```
  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name = "some_map")
  @MapKeyColumn(name = "name")
  @Column(name = "value")
  @Convert(converter = SomeStringConverter.class)
  private Map<String, String> colors;
```

The [Hibernate source for the stack from the error](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.6/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/CollectionPropertyHolder.java#L113) explicitly states:

> JPA says that @Convert on a Map always needs to specify attributeName of key/value (or prefixed with key./value. for embedded paths).

However, while [the API for Convert](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.2/api/javax/persistence/Convert.html) lists a few conditions under which `attributeName` has to be specified, a map of basic types is not among them, and the page contains an example 5 with a `Map<String, String>` and no `attributeName`.

Correspondingly, when we add `attributeName="value"` to the `@Convert` annotation, Eclipselink gives the error:

> The mapping attribute [colors] from the class [Abc] is not a valid mapping type for a convert using an attribute name specification. An attribute name should only be specified to traverse an Embedded mapping type.

So the two seem to be contradicting each other directly. Is this a bug in one of them, or has the standard changed at some point, or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: I'd say its a Bug. The specification (and JavaDoc) clearly states attribute name is only required if you want to specify it to run on the key. The default for a basic collection of this nature is for it to run on the value, without having to specify the attributeName. The specification is usually quite clear with examples, and clearly did so for the key element, not the value.

Comment: @Chris: I have issued https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15733, and the maintainers seem to have accepted it as such - if you would make an answer from your comment, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EclipseLink behavior here is correct, as the JPA specification (starting in 2.1) section 11.1.10 states :

> The Convert annotation may be applied to a basic attribute or to an
> element collection of basic type (in which case the converter is
> applied to the elements of the collection). In these cases, the
> attributeName element must not be specified.

Which makes this against the specification to require the attributeName on this mapping.

See [HHH-15733](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15733) for details of the bug within Hibernate.